# The method 'selectTime' isn't defined for the class '_createWeckerPage'

Tags: flutter, dart

I used a casual showTimePicker in our first dart file (main.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
//import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CreateWeckerPage('Wecker erstellen'),
    );
  }
}



class CreateWeckerPage extends StatefulWidget{
  CreateWeckerPage(this.name):super();
  final String name;
  @override
  _CreateWeckerPage createState() => _CreateWeckerPage();
}

class _CreateWeckerPage extends State<CreateWeckerPage>{
  TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now();

  //Zeit Picker Funktion
  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context, 
      initialTime: _time, 
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
          child: child,
        );
      }
    );

    if(picked != null && picked != _time){
      print('Timeselected: ${_time.toString()}');
      setState((){
        _time = picked;
      });
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${widget.name}')
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Time Selected: ${_time.toString()}'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                _selectTime(context);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Zeit eingeben",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I wanted to refector the code and started to outsource the page in another dart file and the function _selectTime into another dart file for the functions. So i created a file which is called createWeckerPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:wecker/Funktions/timePicker.dart';

class CreateWeckerPage extends StatefulWidget{
  CreateWeckerPage(this.name):super();
  final String name;
  @override
  _CreateWeckerPage createState() => _CreateWeckerPage();
}

class _CreateWeckerPage extends State<CreateWeckerPage>{
  TimeOfDay _time;   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${widget.name}')
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Time Selected: ${_time.toString()}'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                  testClass.testFunktion();
                  _time = _selectTime(context):
                );  
              },
              child: Text(
                "Zeit eingeben",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and a timePicker.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

 Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {

  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
    context: context, 
    initialTime: _time, 
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
        child: child,
      );
    }
  );

  if(picked != null && picked != _time){
    print('Timeselected: ${_time.toString()}');
    return picked;
  }
  return _time;
}
```

The problem is, as written in the title that the method _selectTime is not defined in the createWeckerPage Class. How can I implement my Future _selectTime function to work inside my createWeckerPage.dart to display in the app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

underline means private, you can remove _ underline 
please change from

```
_selectTime(BuildContext context)
```

to

```
selectTime(BuildContext context)
```